# Can't type double number on android

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I have an Xamarin Forms Application with an entry defined as follows:

```
<Entry x:Name="AmountEntry"
               Text="{Binding SelectedPayment.Amount}"
               Keyboard="Numeric"
               HorizontalTextAlignment="End"
               Focused="AmountFieldGotFocus" />
```

The Property in Amount is just a simple doulbe property:

```
    public double Amount {
        get => amount;
        set {
            if (Math.Abs(amount - value) < 0.01) return;
            amount = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged();
        }
    }
```

This works in most regions fine with all kinds of numbers. But I have a report of a user having a russian region setting and he can't enter any doulbe numbers. I am able to reproduce it when I set the emulator to the following language settings:

[image]

The comma is written, but removed when the next number is typed. The point from the numeric keyboard isn't written at all. The interessting thing is, that it is working when I remove the Keyboard="Numeric" and just write a point. Do I have to handle that different in certain regions?

Here is a Screenvideo which shows the issue nicely: https://github.com/MoneyFox/MoneyFox/files/3140027/device-2019-05-02-183502.zip

If helpful the repository is on GitHub: https://github.com/MoneyFox/MoneyFox
The related files are the ModifyPaymentUserControl in the presentation project and the PaymentViewModel in the Service Project.

Issue in the Xamarin Forms repository: https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/6167

Comment: if it's easy to reproduce, I would file an issue with Xamarin: https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues

Comment: good idea. although I'm not sure if that is a bug with my application, Xamarin Forms, Xamarin.Android or Android.

Comment: @NPadrutt as you are doing it in Forms create an issue for Forms. They will check wher the problem is. Also, try creating a simple clean solution and try reproducing it there. Then you are good to fill a bug

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with decimal separator and regions. At the end i decided to set the dot `.` as THE decimal separator for my App.

This is achieved by simply calling the following method from the `App` class in the **Shared Project**:

```
/// <summary>
/// Sets a custom culture which is the same as the device's culture
/// but with the dot "." as the decimal separator.
/// </summary>
/// <remarks>
/// This is particularly important in order to be able to use Keyboard.Numeric,
/// since the Keyboard.Numeric shows always dot for decimal separators independently 
/// of the Culture (De-de should use comma ",").
/// </remarks>
public static void SetCustomCulture()
{
    CultureInfo customCulture = (CultureInfo)System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Clone();
    customCulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator = ".";

    System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = customCulture;
}
```

---

I hope this helps you. If you find a better solution, let me know!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried this out, but it seems not to work for me (maybe I'm doing something wrong). The dot still isn't written. It seems like it doesn't even write the dot since the setter is not executed. Although this does work when I use another keyboard.

Comment: I added a video to my initial post to better display how the issue manifests.